# Dropdown values lost after page reload ,

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, dropdown

Javascript code for sending value to server through ajax

In my code , status  value can be different for different vulnerable name .

Upon choosing one status value among  different options , stored it in database by sending value to server through ajax,but after refreshing  webpage, selected value is lost , I want to see  last selected option value even after page reloads,

please visit sample image link once.  [sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uttYG.png)

```js
< script >
  function statusval(value, vulname, vul_id) {
    var sv = value;
    var vn = vulname;
    var vi = vul_id;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    var data = "s_name=" + sv + "&v_name=" + vn + "&v_id=" + vi;
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "status.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(data);
  } <
  /script>
```

```html
<form method='post' action='status.php' id='status'>
  <select name='status' id='status' onchange='statusval(this.value,\"$_vulname\",\"$_vul_id\")'>
   <option value=''>Status</option>
  <option value='Open'>Open</option>
  <option value='closed'>Closed</option>
  <option value='Partially Fixed'>Partially Fixed</option>
</select>
  <input type='hidden' name='vulname' value='$_vulname' id='vulname'>
  <input type='hidden' name='vul_id' value='$_vul_id' id='vul_id'>
</form>
```

Comment: developers can see webpage image on click ( enter image description here) just above code .

Comment: isn't that what your profile reads as, "Web Developer" ? sorry but I for one have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: dropdown value lost when i reload webpage , how can retain selected value of dropdown?

Comment: If you want to retain a selected option in a dropdown then two things have got to happen. Firstly you have to save that selection somewhere, e.g. in the session or in a db. Secondly, you then have to load that value in the PHP, how you saved it while dictate how you load it.

Comment: i did'nt get you , can u please show me one example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are able to retrieve the status from the database together with `$_vulname` and `$_vul_id`. Let's say you store the value in `$_status`. Then you can simply check for each option, if the status matches the value and set the `selected` attribute:

```
<option value=''>Status</option>
<option value='Open'" . (($_status === 'Open') ? ' selected' : '') . ">Open</option>
<option value='closed'" . (($_status === 'closed') ? ' selected' : '') . ">Closed</option>
```

Comment: tnku very much :) it worked wow :)) amazing got reply in within hours tnku @masterfloda.